# Eclipse setup cannot resolve imports

Tags: android, eclipse, monkeyrunner

I am trying to create a MonkeyRunner program in Java using Eclipse but :

```
import com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbBackend; 
import com.android.monkeyrunner.core.IMonkeyDevice; 
import com.android.monkeyrunner.core.TouchPressType;
```

cannot be found.

Can someone point me a tutorial to import those files/jars in Eclipse?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like I misinformed you. After reading more, the answer can be found here http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html#Plugins That should tell you how to use the plugins

Comment: Which jars should I download ? I think the following packages is from android source

Comment: Edited my answer. I was under the impression that you just needed to import jars for source code you downloaded online. But since MonkeyRunner is used to allow Python to load and use android apps my first answer was wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, though it's not very clear in your question, that your intention is to use monkey from Java, in that case you can follow the steps described in http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2011/11/android-using-monkey-from-java.html